# Problems with Firefox 4 new click event behavior

Tags: javascript, firefox, mootools, click, mouseclick-event

I have a problem with the behavior of Firefox 4 in regards to parameters passed to the function that is getting called upon a click event.

Take a look at this example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.11/mootools.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="e">Klick mich!</span> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("e").addEvent("click", function(a, b, c){
            alert(this);
            alert(a);
            alert(b);
            alert(c);
            console.log(this);
            console.log(a);
            console.log(b);
            console.log(c);
        }.bind(1, [2, 3]));
    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

If you open this with Firefox 4 the result is:

1. 1
2. 2,3
3. object MouseEvent
4. undefined

In any other browser the result is:

1. 1
2. 2
3. 3
4. undefined

As you can see only Firefox 4 passes an MouseEvent to the function. This behavior breaks a lot of my code.

Do you know any solution? Thanks for help.

**EDIT1**: Chrome behaves like FF4

Comment: I don't see any problem here. Firefox behaves as expected, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: The problem is that different versions of Firefox behave differently. If you have FF4 installed its very easy for you to reproduce this by copy&paste the above html into a local file and open it with FF4 and IE.

Comment: I tried Opera and I got the "any other browser" result. However, Opera doesn't support Function.prototype.bind natively so the above code without the MooTools library would give an error message. Hence I assume that MooTools offers some implementation of bind() method that is incompatible with ES5 and ES5-compliant browsers (like Fx4). I'd recommend not using bind() or try newer version of MooTools. The Firefox 4's behaviour is correct, any other result is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is - this is mootools 1.11 - **UNSUPPORTED AND OLD**

in mootools 1.11, it was accepted to use ( http://docs111.mootools.net/Native/Function.js#Function.bind ):

> bind  optional, the object that the “this” of the function will refer to.
>
> args  optional, the arguments passed. must be an array if arguments > 1

hence, doing .bind(1, [args]) `was` correct. However, recently the native `Function.bind` implementation changed in browsers that implement it - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

> thisArg    The value to be passed as the this parameter to the target function when the bound function is called.  The value is ignored if the bound function is constructed using the new operator.
>
> arg1, arg2, ...    Arguments to prepend to arguments provided to the bound function when invoking the target function.

it means, to make it work you need `.bind(1,2,3,4);` where 1 is bound scope and 2,3,4 are arguments.

you **SHOULD** upgrade, running mootools 1.11 on browsers that came 4 years after it got written will yield unpredictable results. always. for example, 1.11 won't detect gecko/ff anymore due to deprecated func used to test for it.

what next, check for netscape4? :)

Comment: If I do what you suggested I get my code working in FF4 but it won't work in IE8 ^^
Thanks for pointing out that Firefox 4 uses JavaScript 1.8.5. I assumed that the function "bind" of Javascript 1.8.5 is overwritten by the mootools implementation. It isn't.
Also, I already solved this by using jQuery instead of MooTools but I was interested in why it didn't work. Thanks again for clearing up things.